# Does Facebook Limit Range of Functionality Available to New Apps?

Tags: facebook-fql, feed

The "Include recent activity stories" migration setting, for instance, is not available on a new app. Is the  new setting mentioned below restricted to certain app types?

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/592/

I have a 'website' application that doesn't expose this setting in the Advanced section.

It seems Facebook enforces a 'graduated licencing' program for apps where they start off with limited functionality but gradually gain more rights as some factors (i.e. age, # of users, reputation of owners, etc) improve?